# Swap multiple divs that contain multiple google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to have several gmaps on one page that are in hidden divs and swapped out. First map shows up fine but all following ones when called are part grey and off center. I've seen many posts as such but none of the solutions have worked - even google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

Here's what I have. Thanks for any help.

```
function displayMap() {
document.getElementById('map_canvas').style.display="block";
initialize();}
function displayMap2() {
document.getElementById('map_canvas2').style.display="block";
initialize();}
function displayMap3() {
document.getElementById('map_canvas3').style.display="block";
initialize();}
function displayMap4() {
document.getElementById('map_canvas4').style.display="block";
initialize();
}
  function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.924186, -75.297571);
  var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(40.152785, -76.750233);
  var myLatlng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(39.962254, -75.605264);
  var myLatlng4 = new google.maps.LatLng(40.152785, -76.750233);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var mapOptions2 = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var mapOptions3 = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var mapOptions4 = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas2'), mapOptions2);
  var map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas3'), mapOptions3);
  var map4 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas4'), mapOptions4);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng2,
      map: map2
  });
  var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng3,
      map: map3
  });
  var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng4,
      map: map4
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The swap div script

```
     jQuery(function(){
     jQuery('#showall').click(function(){
           jQuery('.targetDiv').show();
    });
    jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
          jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
          jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
    });
    });
```

The html

```
    <div class="left_club" style="float:left; width:200px; margin-right:15px;">
    <h3>Men's Clubs</h3>
    <p><a class="showSingle" target="1" onclick="displayMap()">Royal Legends VBC</a><br>
    <a class="showSingle" target="2" onclick="displayMap2()">Yorktowne VBC</a></p>

    <h3>Women's Clubs</h3>
    <p><a class="showSingle" target="3" onclick="displayMap3()">Lokahi</a><br>
    <a class="showSingle" target="4" onclick="displayMap4()">Yorktowne VBC</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="targetDiv" id="div1" style=" display:inline;">
    <h2>Royal Legends VBC</h2>
    <p>Contact | <a href="mailto:sample.com">sample</a><br>
Location | Clifton Heights, PA 19018<br>
Phone Number | sample<br>
Website | <a href="http://sample.com/" target="_blank">sample</a>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="targetDiv" id="div2">
    <h2>Yorktowne VBC</h2>
    <p>Contact | <a href="mailto:sample.com">sample</a><br>
Location | Etters PA 17319<br>
Phone Number | sample<br>
Website | <a href="http://www.sample.com/" target="_blank">sample</a>
    <div id="map_canvas2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="targetDiv" id="div3">
    <h2>Lokahi</h2>
    <p>Contact | <a href="mailto:sample.net">sample</a><br>
Location | West Chester PA 19380<br>
Phone Number | sample<br>
    <div id="map_canvas3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="targetDiv" id="div4">
    <h2>Yorktowne VBC</h2>
    <p>Contact | <a href="mailto:sample.com">sample</a><br>
Location | Etters PA 17319<br>
Phone Number | sample<br>
Website | <a href="http://www.sample.com/" target="_blank">Yorktowne VBC</a>
    <div id="map_canvas4"></div>
    </div
```

The css

```
    #map_canvas {margin-top:10px;width: 455px;height: 240px;float:left;border:1px solid #dcdcdc; margin-left:0px; margin-bottom:0px;}
    #map_canvas2 {margin-top:10px;width: 455px;height: 240px;float:left;border:1px solid #dcdcdc; margin-left:0px; margin-bottom:0px;}
    #map_canvas3 {margin-top:10px;width: 455px;height: 240px;float:left;border:1px solid #dcdcdc; margin-left:0px; margin-bottom:0px;}
    #map_canvas4 {margin-top:10px;width: 455px;height: 240px;float:left;border:1px solid #dcdcdc; margin-left:0px; margin-bottom:0px;}
    .showSingle {cursor:pointer;}
    .targetDiv {float:left; width:458px; padding:20px;border:1px solid #dcdcdc; background-color:#f0efee;}
```

js to hide maps after first map

```
    jQuery(function(){
    $('#div2, #div3, #div4').hide();
    });
```

Comment: Can you show us your CSS?

Comment: you cant work with hide and show, it results in display:none and that will cause the map to fck up when you initialize it and then hide and show.When you show it you will only see one map-square on top left. to avoid this, you have to keep static width and height, so visibility:hidden is our friend or position:absolute and left:-9999px if not shown and if show left:0, sth like that

Comment: I added the css for the map callouts and the hide following maps function. Thanks. KM

Comment: Where would I place the specifics you suggest @johnSmith?

Comment: I posted the css @deweyredman. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this problem very good here is one of the possible solutions stated in my comment,

The Problem is, when you initiate a google map on an element with width and height and after that set it to display:none and then display:block again (hide/show) it will fck up the map.

Now on this fiddle, when another map is shown or any map gets hidden the width and height of the containers are not affected, they are just moved horizontaly, 
http://jsfiddle.net/LNYSE/

css, all maps are initialy positioned somewhere so left, users dont see.

```
.targetDiv {position:absolute;top:220px; width:458px;left:-999px; padding:20px;border:1px solid #dcdcdc; background-color:#f0efee;}
```

html, only the first map is visible because left:0

```
<div class="targetDiv activeYo" id="div1" style=" display:inline;left:0;">
```

here´s the js, you dont need to use a animate function you could also only use `.css('left',0)`

```
jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
    jQuery('.activeYo').animate({left:-999}).removeClass('activeYo');
    jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).animate({left:0}).addClass('activeYo');
});
```

without animate http://jsfiddle.net/LNYSE/1/

cheers

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know. Thanks for your help @johnSmith.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the help @johnSmith. Anyway to minimize the js as I have some pages that will have over 25 maps. Thanks again. KM

Comment: you could also initate the map just before the next div shows up, ideally you would save geocoordinates in data-attributes in the divs so you can get rid of a lot konfiguration part in js

Comment: Thanks @johnSmith. That cuts the js down.